# Dependency injection in Android Library

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, koin

I'm working on Android library that other apps will use it.
This library will not have any activity, but it will have Fragments, VM, domain etc.
So far on my apps i worked with Dagger2, and i'm not sure how it will work in library.
Anyone have experience with it? or maybe someone can recommend other library to use for that case (koin?)?

Thanks

Comment: You can use dagger internally, but you can't depend on your host app using dagger, and thus providing objects to you via dagger.  Basically you'll have to create a main object that will set up your components and provide the injection context for your own internal classes.

Answer (score -1):

`Koin` is far more easy to use. You can also get rid of annotations and their handling. Suppose we have a class name `Helper` and needs to be access from different locations.

Implementation Steps:

a) Add Dependency in `build.gradle(app)`.

```
implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.3.0"
```

b) Create a class extend it with `KoinComponent`

```
class DIComponent : KoinComponent {

    // Utils
    val helper by inject<Helper>()
}
```

c) Initialize `Koin` by passing it modules in `App` class

```
class MainApplication : Application(){
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        
        startKoin{
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MainApplication)
            modules(appModule)
        }
    }

    private val appModule = module {
        single { Helper() }
    }
}
```

d) Now, to use this class in project (activity/fragment)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val diComponent = DIComponent()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        diComponent.helper.yourFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it is work the same for Android library? i don't have app on my library, so i can't rely on that.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Give it a try

Comment: Thanks. I will. So i can init koin everywhere in my app?

Comment: It is recommended to init in app class.

Comment: As i wrote, it's a 3rd party library, so i don't have app or not even activity. should i use my "gate" fragment for that?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just make sure to start it at the very start